# array implementation using python from scratch

Tags: python, arrays

My teacher has asked me to implement an array using python without using any inbuilt functions but I am confused and I don't know how to? this is the complete question...

```
Write a program in Python to implement the “Array” data structure. Perform operations like add or insert, delete or remove and display. Your program should be able to add/insert at any position in an array or remove/delete any element from an array. Take care of extreme conditions such as an empty array or full array and display an appropriate message to the user.
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hope this might help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-data-structure/

Comment: And / or ask your teacher.

Comment: It's a ridiculous question. How can the "full array" constraint be given when no limits are stated? It makes no sense. Your teacher *probably* wants you to write an Array class but how you'd achieve that without using any built-in functions is a mystery to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the array in a list L, and write a function for each list operation. For example, to search for an element x in a list L and return the index of the first occurrence of x in L, rather than using the built-in function index, you would implement the linear search algorithm.  So, the following code would be incorrect because it uses the built-in function index:

```
def search(L,x):
    return L.index(x)
```

The following code would be acceptable because you are implementing the linear search algorithm yourself (presumably your teacher wants you to write programs from scratch, which is very good practice):

```
def search(L,x):
    #input: a list L and an element x
    #output: the index of first occurrence of x in L, or -1 if x not in L
    n = len(L)
    for i in range(n):
        if L[i] == x:
            return i
    return -1    

L=[3,1,4,2]
print(search(L,7))
```